# JtextPane of one Line

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane

I want to implement a JTextField with custom fonts.I came to know that we cannot do that in JTextField.  Now I am using JtextPane i have a problem How to make sure the carat doesn't go to the next line when the user press enter.  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a DocumentFilter and prevent inserting "\n" chars there.

Comment: I tried this but i am not able to get \n in the insertString function of DocumentFilter class. Can you give more idea ?

Comment: Use the String argument. Cut all \n chars and pass the changed string.

Answer (score 2):

```
class DocFilter extends DocumentFilter{

        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(offset, string.replaceAll("\\n", ""), attr); 
        }

       public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(offset, string.replaceAll("\\n", ""), attr); 
        }
    }
```

This code works well

Answer (score 0):

Add keyListener to jTextPane and track for enter key in `keyPressed(e)` method. Key code for enter is 10.

---

Try key bindings like this:

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
// Get KeyStroke for enter key
KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0);
// Override enter for a pane
String actionKey = "none";
InputMap map = pane.getInputMap();
map.put(enterKey, actionKey);
```

This will override the enter key behavior for textPane and does not do anything if user presses enter.

Comment: What happen when a user copy and paste a text containing new lines?

Comment: When the user presses enter i can take my carat to first line. But that is not i want to be done what if the user clicks ?

Comment: @Vivien: that time this will not work but I don't think cares about this.

Comment: @Arjit: why take caret to first line instead when user presses enter remove the last added character form textPane that is new line.

Comment: Adding and removing would be shown on a screen it may be fast but i would be shown. I have tried that but it shows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But would it give notification for keypressed enter on the JTextPane ?

Comment: And I think this would be for TextPane or mapping would be for the enter. I mean when ever the enter is pressed

Comment: @Arjit: it is only for textPane not for all frame.